How do I fix the wiring for smart switches?
I recently bought a house that was built in 1972. The wiring is old and sometimes wrong from years of DIY mods and renovations. I am comfortable with mechanical and electrical work but I'm not an electrician. I tried to upgrade a few "dummy" switches to z-wave smart switches. Initially, I thought the house did not have neutral wires run because none of the old switches had neutral terminals. Later, I realized the neutral wires were covered with tape in the back of the jbox. Luckily, the zwave switches I bought worked in neutral and no-netural configurations. First, I wired the switches in the no-neutral configuration using the included jumper(s) that goes from ground to neutral. Everything "worked" but I wasn't comfortable leaving it that way once I found the hidden neutrals in the jboxes. After rewiring the switches using the neutrals I can't get the lights to work anymore. The goal is to have a 3-way switch for one light and a dimmer for the other light. I've tried the following configurations but I either get a flickering light on the 3-way or no light at all but the switches make the clicking sound as if they are turning on/off. What am I doing wrong?
Diagram:



Enbrighten Z-Wave Plus Switch 47900
Enbrighten Add-On Switch 46199
Enbrighten Z-Wave Plus Dimmer 52252


are the neutral wires connected at the breaker panel?

I'm not sure, I plan to trace the wires in the light fixture this weekend when I have more time... I don't understand how the light fixture has 5 romex wires going to it but only two switches... I especially don't understand why that white wire is bundled with the 4 black wires!?! I feel like this house should have burned down long ago if any other are like! My guess is they don't all go back to the panel?

When you changed the new smart switch wiring to use your newly found neutrals, did you add the smart switch neutral terminal to the existing bundle with a 'pigtail' or did you remove one of the white wires from the bundle and connect it to the switch by itself?

You have a lot of info here.  First thing is to learn some basics of home electric and wiring.
common switches that are not "smart" switches or timers simply open and close the power (Hot) to a load. They do not need a neutral as the neutral is not opened or closed.  However all circuits require a neutral for returning power to the breaker box. Therefore you will find neutrals in the junction boxes, but not connected to any switch.( A neutral will be connected to an outlet.) In some older homes there can be a switch that has a black and white wire attached. These are known as switch loops and are no longer allowed by code.
All switches and outlets should be grounded. exceptions are those in a metal box where the box itself is grounded.  It is common for a electrician to put the grounds to the back of the box then the neutral bundle and have any hot wires near the front. (Always look deep in the box for wires. Some can be tucked back pretty far.)
Now, It looks line the 3 way switch is wired correctly, however the add-on switch is not. You would need a 3way there also.
The dimmer has no power in, unless the white wire you have is connected to power (needs to be marked with black tape) then you have no neutral.

Yep, I'm just discovering that several switches have (neutral) wires tucked in the back and covered with tape and paint! I missed them when I was initially trying to figure out what was going on!
The add-on switch is a bit odd (which is why I included links to the user guide). The addon switch doesn't use line power. instead, it just uses the low voltage from the traveler to relay state info back to the 47900 switch and doesn't function as a true "3 way".
The dimmer has line power from the black wire and load is on the white wire. The dimmer is specifically designed without a neutral.

I believe what you may have is a white wire at the  add-on switch that is not a neutral, in that it does not have a path back to the breaker box. It is just like a traveler. Whereas I believe the manufacturer wants you to pigtail a neutral or a "Jumper" to the dimmer and the add-on switch.
